# Shortcut to change property to full property

Tags: c#, visual-studio, properties, shortcut, code-snippets

I already have a property like this

```
public int MyProperty{get; set;}
```

I need to change this property as a full property like this

```
private int myVar;

public int MyProperty
{
    get { return myVar;}
    set { myVar = value;}
}
```

any shortcut available in VS2013 for this?

Comment: did you or did you not used "prop" keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I was looking for was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

In VS2015, Right click on `myVar` -> Quick Actions...-> Encapsulate field

Even better if you first rename it as `m_myVar` -> Visual studio will generate a property named `MyVar`

Don't have VS2013 right now, but should be the same, maybe no need for "Quick actions..."

Answer (score 1):

Type ***`"propfull"`*** in the editor and press `TAB` twice, ***change the property type*** if desired.
Press `TAB` again to ***change backing name and property name*** if desired.